# Swift Firebase ServerTime.timestamp() is returning negative date.

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database

I seem to be getting a negative value returned from my Firebase call. I store the date value like so:

```
["ctn": ServerValue.timestamp()]
```

When I check the database, it has:

```
 "users" {
     "$uid" {
          "ctn" : "1505930238317"
     }
 }
```

When I try to get that out of the db and print it like so:

```
dbRootRef.child("users").child(user.getUserUID()).child("ctn").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        if let item = snapshot.value as? Int{
            timeNow = item
            print("db time \(item)")
        }
}
```

The console shows:

> db time -1603282711

Any ideas?

Comment: Try using `NSNumber`, `Int64` or `UInt64` instead of `Int`

Comment: Indeed, `Int32(truncatingBitPattern: 1505930238317 as UInt64)` returns `-1603282711` – apparently you are on a 32-bit architecture. This "hidden truncation" is fixed in Swift 4: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0170-nsnumber_bridge.md.

Answer (score 0):

Timestamps are very large numbers and in most typed languages, they do not fit into the limits of the Integer data type.

You are getting a negative value because in casting the timestamp to an integer, you have caused it to [overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow).

Use the `Double` or `UInt64` data types instead of `Int` and you should see the correct value.

```
if let item = snapshot.value as? UInt64 {
    timeNow = item // ensure that timeNow is declared as a UInt64
    print("db time \(item)")
}
```

Comment: When i use your code, xcode asks me to change timeNow = item to `timeNow = Int(item)` and then crashes

Comment: @JamesG again you need to change your timeNow type

Comment: @JamesG Your timestamp is in *milliseconds.* If you divide it by 1000.0 then it should fit into an  `Int` on all platforms.